# Tensorflow Warning: TensorFlow was not built with CUDA kernel binaries compatible with compute capability 8.6

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, compute-capability

I have an old Intel Core i7 950 CPU with **no AVX support**, a newer NVIDIA RTX 3060 Ti GPU with **compute capability 8.6**, and the Windows 10 OS. Despite the default Tensorflow distribution requiring AVX support, after MANY trials and errors I was able to install Tensorflow from [this wheel](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/tree/master/2.9.0/py39/CPU%2BGPU/cuda117cudnn8sse2), which was compiled for CPUs with no AVX support.

In order to do so I had to downgrade to python 3.9, CUDA 11.7, cudnn 8.9.5 and NumPy 1.22.4.

Now, when I `import tensorflow as tf` in python I do not get an error message yay!
However, when I try the function: `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')`, I get :

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1943] TensorFlow was not built with CUDA kernel binaries compatible with compute capability 8.6. CUDA kernels will be jit-compiled from PTX, which could take 30 minutes or longer.
```

See the actual outpub below:

```
C:\Users\Luca>python
Python 3.9.13 (tags/v3.9.13:6de2ca5, May 17 2022, 16:36:42) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
2023-09-23 11:37:43.077533: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1943] TensorFlow was not built with CUDA kernel binaries compatible with compute capability 8.6. CUDA kernels will be jit-compiled from PTX, which could take 30 minutes or longer.
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
>>> tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

Now, *the very first* time I ran it, it did take about 30 min to get the result, now *every time* I run it, I get the same output but the result is *immediate* (i.e. don't have to wait 30 minutes to get `[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]`. Note that when I run the same function *in the same session* I don't get the warning again.

1. What causes the Warning to show up every time?
2. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why I was downgraded, but by googling with the term "suppress", I found the answer to my **second question:**

Method 1 (learned from [here](https://saturncloud.io/blog/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-the-messages-tensorflow-prints/#:%7E:text=One%20of%20the%20easiest%20ways,while%20ignoring%20less%20critical%20messages.&text=This%20code%20sets%20the%20logging,to%20only%20printing%20error%20messages.)):

```
import os

# Value for TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL
# 0 = all messages are logged (default behavior)
# 1 = INFO messages are not printed
# 2 = INFO and WARNING messages are not printed
# 3 = INFO, WARNING, and ERROR messages are not printed

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

Method 2 (learned from [here](https:////pypi.org/project/silence-tensorflow/)):

```
pip install silence_tensorflow
```

Then add:

```
from silence_tensorflow import silence_tensorflow
silence_tensorflow()
```

I still don't know the answer to my first question...

Thanks

Comment: Telling it not to print the warning doesn't fix the thing it was warning about.  Fortunately for your use-case, it apparently caches the JIT-compile results across runs, so it ended up not being a problem (as long as you don't do anything that would make it use a different kernel that has to get JITed; I don't know if that can happen just calling different tensorflow functions on different data sets or anything.)  Another way to get rid of the warning would be to compiler a version of the library without AVX but with support for CUDA compute 8.6, assuming that's possible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I don't have the skill to compile it from source and the instructions on the TF site are a bit above my head, but yes, specifically compile it for GPU with compute capability of 8.6 would solve the problem at it's root, if that's possible.